# Whoosh, Haystack, and AttributeError: 'Segment' object has no attribute 'compound' in production only

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm using Whoosh 2.3.2, Haystack 2.0.0, and Django 1.3 under Python 2.7. On Localhost, it works great. In production, it explodes when I search.

Here's the full traceback:

```
File "/opt/Python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 117, in get_response
     response = middleware_method(request, e)

   File "/opt/Python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/views.py", line 50, in __call__
     return self.create_response()

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/views.py", line 130, in create_response
     (paginator, page) = self.build_page()

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/views.py", line 107, in build_page
     self.results[start_offset:start_offset + self.results_per_page]

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/query.py", line 261, in __getitem__
     self._fill_cache(start, bound)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/query.py", line 159, in _fill_cache
     results = self.query.get_results(**kwargs)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/backends/__init__.py", line 478, in get_results
     self.run(**kwargs)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/backends/__init__.py", line 396, in run
     results = self.backend.search(final_query, **search_kwargs)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/backends/__init__.py", line 27, in wrapper
     return func(obj, query_string, *args, **kwargs)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/apps/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py", line 346, in search
     narrow_searcher = self.index.searcher()

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/utils/whoosh/index.py", line 322, in searcher
     return Searcher(self.reader(), fromindex=self, **kwargs)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/utils/whoosh/filedb/fileindex.py", line 335, in reader
     info.generation, reuse=reuse)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/utils/whoosh/filedb/fileindex.py", line 322, in _reader
     readers = [segreader(segment) for segment in segments]

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/utils/whoosh/filedb/fileindex.py", line 311, in segreader
     generation=generation)

   File "/var/www/html/sites/django_projects/utils/whoosh/filedb/filereading.py", line 66, in __init__
     if segment.compound:

  AttributeError: 'Segment' object has no attribute 'compound'
```

And here's my search_index.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from articles.models import Article
from django.conf import settings

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

class ArticleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Article

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(publication="Published", site=settings.SITE_ID, created__lte=now)
```

Anyone familiar with this or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. As it turns out, Haystack and Whoosh must be installed to site-packages. Having them in an apps folder causes problems, especially if you have a utils folder laying around.